# Pandas: Combine rows having same date different time into a single row of the same date(consolidate partial data of different time for same identity)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

I have a sample dataframe as given below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NaN = np.nan
data = {'ID':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B'],
    'Date':['2021-09-20 04:34:57', '2021-09-20 04:37:25', '2021-09-20 04:38:26', '2021-09-01 
    00:12:29','2021-09-01 11:20:58','2021-09-02 09:20:58'],
    'Name':['xx',NaN,NaN,'yy',NaN,NaN],
    'Height':[174,NaN,NaN,160,NaN,NaN],
    'Weight':[74,NaN,NaN,58,NaN,NaN],
    'Gender':[NaN,'Male',NaN,NaN,'Female',NaN],
    'Interests':[NaN,NaN,'Hiking,Sports',NaN,NaN,'Singing']}

 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
 df1
```

[image]
I want to combine the data present on the same date into a single row. The 'Date' column is in timestamp format.
The final output should look like the image shown below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question. Most of the columns has np.nan values instead of Empty string. May be this is causing the error.

Comment: @SeaBean I tried your updated solution. Now the columns having integer/numerical values are dropped. I want to have all columns in the dataframe without dropping any. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: your revised data simply doesn't run.  `160cm` not putting in quotes is not a legitimate text.  Do you mean string of it ?   `'160cm'` instead ?

Comment: Its updated @SeaBean 160 is an integer. Others are string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New Solution

The old solution was based on initial version of question where empty strings instead of `NaN` values were used for undefined values and all columns were of string types.  With updated question using `NaN` for undefined values (and even when also updated to have different column data types of numeric and string types), the solution can be simplified  as follows:

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) to group by `ID` and date (without time) and then aggregate the `NaN` and non-`NaN` elements with the ***latest*** (asssuming column `Date` is presented in chronological order) non-`NaN` values for an `ID`, as follows:

```
# Convert `Date` to datetime format
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

# Sort `df1` with ['ID', 'Date'] order if not already in this order
#df1 = df1.sort_values(['ID', 'Date'])

df_out = (df1.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')])
             .last()
             .reset_index()
         ).replace([None], [np.nan])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


   ID       Date Name Height Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20   xx  174.0   74.0    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01   yy  160.0   58.0  Female            NaN
2  B 2021-09-02  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        Singing
```

#### Old Solution

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) to group by `ID` and date and then aggregate the `NaN` and non-`NaN` elements, as follows:

```
# Convert `Date` to datetime format
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df_out = (df1.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')])
             .agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna().astype(str)))
             .reset_index()
         ).replace('', np.nan)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


   ID       Date Name Height Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20   xx  174.0   74.0    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01   yy  160.0   58.0  Female            NaN
2  B 2021-09-02  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        Singing
```

As your original question had all columns of string types, the above codes work fine to give results of all columns as string types.  However, your edited question has data with both numeric and string types. In order to retain the original data types, we can modify the codes as follows:

```
# Convert `Date` to datetime format
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df_out = (df1.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')])
             .agg(lambda x: np.nan if len(w:=x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)) == 0 else w)
             .reset_index()
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


   ID       Date Name Height Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20   xx  174.0   74.0    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01   yy  160.0   58.0  Female            NaN
2  B 2021-09-02  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        Singing


print(df_out.dtypes)

ID                   object
Date         datetime64[ns]
Name                 object
Height              float64            <==== retained as numeric dtype
Weight              float64            <==== retained as numeric dtype
Gender               object
Interests            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: @Corralien  That's the reason I had to quote also the list of column names here.  I think the same warning but solved with the column names.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Strange behavior ?!? I have not this warning with Grouper

Comment: @Corralien  Pandas just sometimes with strange behavior, I agree !  :-)

Comment: @SeaBean I tried implementing you solution as well using Grouper(). But again, I am losing all the columns having 'String' values in them. For both when I used .agg() and .sum().

Comment: @Shiva  See my edit above.  Enhanced answer to cater for your revised sample data with `NaN` values instead of empty strings.

Comment: @SeaBean I tried your updated solution. Now the columns having integer/numerical values are dropped. I want to have all columns in the dataframe without dropping any. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Shiva  See my edit above.  Added `.astype(str)` after `dropna()`

Comment: @SeaBean Works Perfectly. Thanks a lot! This was a tricky one.

Comment: @Shiva  Great it works now after you clarified and updated your sample data to resemble better your real data.

Comment: @Shiva  What's the Python version you are using ?

Comment: @SeaBean My python version is 3.8.5

Comment: @Shiva  That's fine then.  See my cleaned up edit above.  With new codes to retain your data types for numeric columns.  As your original question had all columns of string types, the initial version will give all string types as result.  New version to handle this.

Comment: @Shiva  With further thought, your revised question with `NaN` as undefined values can be supported with simpler codes using ` GroupBy.last()`.  Take a look at the new version at the top of the edited solution.  This supports both numeric as well as strings columns.

Answer (score 2):

Start first by converting to datetime and flooring:

```py
In [3]: df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.floor('D')

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  ID       Date Name Height Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20   xx  174cm   74kg
1  A 2021-09-20                       Male
2  A 2021-09-20                             Hiking,Sports
3  B 2021-09-01   yy  160cm   58kg
4  B 2021-09-01                     Female
5  B 2021-09-02                                   Singing
```

Now using `groupby` and `sum`:

```py
In [5]: df.groupby(["ID", "Date"]).sum().reset_index()
Out[5]:
  ID       Date Name Height Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20   xx  174cm   74kg    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01   yy  160cm   58kg  Female
2  B 2021-09-02                                   Singing
```

Comment: Your idea is good (I choose the same method in the same time) +1.

Comment: @ddejohn I tried implementing this. But for some reason, the columns having string values are all removed in the final dataframe after using groupby() line.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are correctly ordered as your sample, you can merge your data as below:

```
>>> df1.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')]) \
       .sum().reset_index()

  ID       Date Name Height Weight  Gender      Interests
0  A 2021-09-20   xx  174cm   74kg    Male  Hiking,Sports
1  B 2021-09-01   yy  160cm   58kg  Female               
2  B 2021-09-02                                   Singing
```

Comment: You've squashed too hard. The row with `Singing` is from `09-02`, but you've grouped it with `09-01`.

Comment: Yes. I saw. I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Yes. Also the time has to be removed in the 'Date' column. Just the Date should be remaining.

Comment: @ Corralien I tried implementing this. But for some reason, the columns having string values are all removed in the final dataframe after using groupby() line. Not sure why this is happening.